# How to set the jdk path in jcreator

Tags: java, jcreator

I have installed *jdk 1.7* in `C:\jdk1.7.0 directory` and *JCreator* in `C:\Program Files directory`. I set the path of correct jdk path in JCreator. But when I try to execute a java program in this I have shown the following messages:

```
          --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Error : Invalid path, "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javac.exe" -g -classpath C:\Users\USER\Documents -d C:\Users\USER\Documents C:\Users\USER\Documents\A.java
```

What is the reason behind this ? Please tell me in a detail and also way to solve this problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issues by deleting the previous Java profile in `Configure`->`Options`->`JDK Profiles`.

Delete everything in it and create a new fresh profile.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows up when the following executable does not exist.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javac.exe
```

Make sure that you have the `jdk` executable installed.

Answer (score -1):

```
Error : Invalid path, "C:\Program Files\bin\javac.exe" -g -classpath   
"C:\Users\HP PAVILION\Desktop\java" -d "C:\Users\HP PAVILION\Desktop\java"   
"C:\Users\HP PAVILION\Desktop\java\das.java"
```

Process completed.

**Error:** Could not find or load main class das

Process completed.