# Compilation error - "The JDK Home Path Has Not Been Set" after installing JDK

Tags: jcreator

I just started using Java in a Computer Science course at school. I installed the JDK, Jcreator and the Doc's on my laptop... But every time I try to compile any program it comes up saying "The JDK Home Path Has Not Been Set". 
What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the jdk path in jcreator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080815/how-to-set-the-jdk-path-in-jcreator)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the previous Java profile in:
Configure->Options->JDK Profiles