# Need help downloading JDK within Java

Tags: java, jcreator

*(BTW moderators, I HAVE checked other questions, and tried their methods which did NOT help in my situation. My primary account got banned from asking questions for 6 days which lead me to create this account.)*

I need help downloading JDK in the java application.

When I try to run my program I am met with the error of "my JDK path was not set". I clicked the button that allowed me to set up a path for it, and I was met with a window with the download link to http://www.javasoft.com .

I go there I get redirected to this site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Upon redirection, I click the "DOWNLOAD" button under the text JDK.
After that I get sent to a webpage that had the JDK download links for each system. Naturally, I click the link for "Windows 64".

After opening the file I meet up with a window that should guide me through the installation. I clicked Next twice, and It downloaded. Then It allows me to put in the location of the Destination folder, the default destination was the exact same as what Jcreator told me to go to. So I proceeded, And it gave me the screen that said "nearly 3 billion devices run Java" and it completed the installation. I got a finish dialogue screen with the option that prompted me to download optional Jcreator programs, of which I declined and clicked "close".

I went to Jcreator again and I was met with the same message saying that my JDK path was not set up. I repeated this process 4-5 times.

*And yes, moderators I HAVE checked other questions, and they all told me the same thing, however The askers of those questions found it solved. They each said to go to the download link and such. When I asked the question on my other account, (which got banned from asking questions for six days) I got either a useless answer(Which got upvoted for no reason) or I get redirected to another question after my question got removed(again, The question I got redirected to, did not solve my problem).*

Comment: Did you read and follow the [installation instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html)? Especially the part about setting up the PATH.

Comment: Also searching Google for [jcreator jdk path](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jcreator%20jdk%20home%20path%20has%20not%20been%20set) brings up lots of answers.

Comment: @Jesper Yes I have tried the installation instructions, it brought me to a list of Operating systems. It didnt give any instructions on how to download JDK.

Comment: And of course I get downvoted again for "not showing any research effort", again, VERY annoying.

Comment: But you have already downloaded and installed the JDK, according to what you write in your question.

Comment: @Jesper Yes, I have downloaded and installed JDK, and I downloaded it in the exact same destination folder as what Jcreator wanted me to put it in. It gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you look at those Google search results? For example: [How to set the jdk path in jcreator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080815/how-to-set-the-jdk-path-in-jcreator) or [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMFKX7E5lW4).

Comment: @Jesper ahh dont worry Jesper, The other answerer solved my problem. Thanks for inquiring though

Answer (score 1):

I don't think downloading the jdk is problem here, but problem is that JDK path is not set up. Set your JAVA_HOME and jdk bin path in PATH variable. That should help.

Let's say your downloaded jdk to "C:\Java\JDK1.8".
Create new environment variable JAVA_HOME = C:\Java\JDK1.8
Edit your environment variable PATH to have C:\Java\JDK1.8\bin

If you are using a command prompt to run the other program, which needs java, close and open a new command window for the new env vars to be of effect.

Here is how you set up these env variables:

**Set the JAVA_HOME  & PATH Variable**

Once you have the JDK installation path:

1. Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select Properties.
2. Click the Advanced tab. Click the Environment Variables button. Under System Variables, click New.
3. Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
4. Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit, which is the jdk path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45) you pasted in comment.
5. Click OK.
6. Find existing PATH variable and edit its value by adding %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the end
7. Click Apply Changes.

You might need to restart windows.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78654/discussion-on-answer-by-moonlighter-need-help-downloading-jdk-within-java).